# Hitting breakpoints in strange order with simple code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was working on some C++ code and noticed my breakpoints were getting hit in a strange order and I don't understand why.  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with cl.exe version 19.35.32215 and link.exe version 14.35.32215.0.  As a simple reproduction I created a new C++ console app with the following code:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> DoSomething()
{
  std::vector<int> results;
  results.push_back(55);
  return results;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> results = DoSomething();
  return 0;
}
```

I put breakpoints on the following two lines:

```
  results.push_back(55);
  return results;
```

I was very surprised when the first breakpoint hit was "return results;".  If I continue code execution I bounce back to "results.push_back(55);" and then move on to "return results;" again.

I was expecting to hit my two breakpoints in their line ordering (i.e. "results.push_back(55)" first, then "return results;").  I've tried both x64 and x86 with a Debug build and both have the same breakpoint weirdness.

I also tried inspecting the disassembly and a box pops up asking me to "Resolve Ambiguity":
[Resolve Ambiguity popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0GgG.png)

I have not tried this same code with gcc or clang.

Can anyone help explain to me what's going on?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know what.

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably only because NRVO (named return value optimization) was applied, so that `results` and the result object of the function are the same object. Then the line initializing `results` is also initializing the return value of the function. I do not think choosing to mark the return statement is useful in that case, but that seems to be how the compiler decided to place the debug information.

Comment: You're either compiling with optimisation or (even if you are compiling without optimisation for debugging) your compiler is applying the NRVO

Comment: I'd suggest, in context of this question, that it doesn't really matter whether the compiler is required to apply the optimisation or not, since it evidently is.   Understanding  what is occurring, that it is not a major concern, and is mandatory in some cases but not others, is possibly sufficient.   Not all compilers conform with all mandatory requirements of the standard (e.g. a quality of implementation concern if they claim conformance, or they support an older standard) and some apply non-mandatory code transformations.

Comment: I thought about NRVO, but I wouldn't expect the debugger to jump around like this (optimizations are indeed off across the board).  The "ambiguity" box that pops up really bothers me too; it's like the compiler generated two copies of my function.

Edit: I also tried compiling the code with /std:c++14 (the default in VS2022), /std:c++17, and /std:c++20, all with the same result.

Comment: Aggressive optimizations -- even mandatory ones that must be executed due to required copy elision -- is a frequent cause of indigestion to debuggers, and to all the meatbags that use the debuggers. You will eventually get used to things like these, and they won't be much of a surprise.

Comment: @BigHands   Debuggers can behave in unexpected or counter-intuitive ways when optimisation is in play.   Sometimes those behaviours get fixed over time (particularly if the unexpected behaviour is a crash, or is grossly misleading) sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `/permissive-` in the compiler, then it applies the optional NVRO even in the Debug configuration. It allocates memory for a returned object on the caller stack frame and passes a pointer to a called function. It can confuse the debugger, that can see `return results` as object construction and initialization that of course should be performed before `push_back()`, but `return` is located in the code after `push_back()`, so it behaves like: user set the breakpoint on the line N, but I have jumped over on the line N+1, I must stop here.

You can disable NVRO with using [`/Zc:nrvo-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-nrvo?view=msvc-170).

Comment: /Zc:nrvo- worked great, thanks!  I think I'll keep this compiler flag set in Debug so my brain stops getting confused with all the jumping around.  Thanks for all the replies to this.

Comment: What's happening is that `std::vector<int> results;`, `return results;`, and the first half of `std::vector<int> results = DoSomething()` are folded into a single logical operation that executes first -- a vector is constructed that will become the `results` vector in `main`.